# Increase php array_slice or skip element?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, csv, slice

Here's my problem, I have a CSV file containing 42,000 SKU records except only the first few and last approximately 3000 need to be processed, the rest of the records are not important and need to be skipped. I'm using array_slice to process 15 records at a time but I can't figure out a good way to skip the proximately 39,000 records in the middle of the file without processing them in blocks of 15. I know all of the SKU's that I don't want to process include the text CNV so I tried using this if statement to skip them and increment increase the limit by 100 to try to quickly get through all the unimportant SKU's.

```
        foreach($import_data as $row_id => $row) {
    if(preg_match('/CNV/',$new_post_meta['_sku'])) {
        $limit = ($limit +100); 
        continue;
    } else {
        $limit = 15; //Set limit back to 15
        //Process each SKU here
```

The problem doing it this way is when it finally gets passed the 39,000 unimportant SKU's then the limit is set to about 1500 so it skips the first 1500 SKU's that need to be processed because the new offset is set to ($limit + $offset). Does anyone have any recommendations to effectively get through the 39,000 SKU's without processing them in small chunks?

The limit is used to set the length of each array_slice like this:

```
$import_data = array_slice($import_data, $offset , ($limit > 0 ? $limit : null), true);
```

Comment: Can you post what is after the if? Where that limit is used. I can't understand why it's important.

Comment: Yes, I just updated my initial question, the limit is used to specify the length of the slice.

Answer (score 1):

That may sound silly, but you could filter your array first, then do whatever you need to do with just the stuff that matters.

```
$import_data = array_filter($import_data, function($value){
    return !preg_match('/CNV/',$value['_sku']); // value here is an item of your array
});

foreach($import_data as $row_id => $row) {
    // process just the $import_data that matters
}
```